# Reflecting native code function arguments in javascript?

Tags: javascript, webkit

Is there a way to investigate the arguments of a function call from the javascript developer console (am using chrome but any will do)?

[I am currently trying to find the signature for webkitGetUserMedia() but have found no documentation anywhere and the console rather unhelpfully only tells me that it is native code without so much as the number of arguments]

Answer (score 0):

Calling `toString()` will return the type signature for non-native functions, but for native functions the arguments are always missing, probably because the Javascript engine itself doesn't know the full signature.

You can get the number of expected arguments by accessing [the length property](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/6.0/#sec-function-instances-length) of the function, but it usually doesn't help much. Better to look for some documentation on the web, for `webkitGetUserMedia()` you can check [here](http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/getusermedia/intro/) and [here](http://w3c.github.io/mediacapture-main/getusermedia.html).